# Adding links to EntityForms on submission confirmation page

Tags: entities

I'm working on a site that has a series of EntityForms I'd like to guide users through. After filling out the initial form, I want the submissions confirmation to recommend subsequent forms based on some of the values in the submission. I figure I can do this with a custom form submission handler, but I was wondering if it would also be possible to do this with Rules. I can make a Rule trigger on EntityForm values, but I don't know what kind of actions to include (I haven't done much with Rules yet).

Any thoughts on using Rules here, or any other approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One rules action you could use would be the `System > Show a message on the site` where you could use replacement patterns to build your recommended links to other forms. This way users would always see the message regardless of the initial entityform redirection page. (This is actually a very handy concept and I will file it away for future use :)

Note: in order to get the replacement patterns you need, you may need to add conditions to your rule in order to make the right data available to the rule.